# What is the difference between "writhe" and " squirm"?

Tags: word-difference

How do you describe a person who is twisting and bending their body in reaction to great physical pain?

I have found ["to writhe"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/writhe) and ["to squirm"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squirm)as verbs, and both of them mean " to make twisted movements". I have noticed that "squirm" is used for "worms" too.

> 1- What is the difference between "writhe" and "squirm"?
>
> 2- Can we use "squirm" for people too or it is considered rude?
>
> 3- What does this sentence (heard in American movies) mean: "I want to watch you squirm"?

Comment: The only common use of "writhe" I can think of is "To writhe in pain" - meaning hurting so bad that you are unconsciously moving without control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can use the word squirm about people

For people, writhing is considered a response to physical pain and squirming a response to embarrassment.

```
I want to watch you squirm
```

Means that I will enjoy your humiliation

Comment: +1. Animals can also *squirm*.  Squirming is a contorting of the body in an attempt to escape a situation (as with human embarrassment, or a puppy trying to get loose and run away).

Comment: For a great practical demonstration of animal squirming, pick up a cat that does not like you.